# Chat server for private social network android

Tags: android, server, raspberry-pi, chat

What is the best way to create a chat app on android? 
I have a RaspBerry Pi and I want to put there a server to support the android app chat but I dont know which is the best software to do that.

Comment: hi what type chat server you are looking ? are you using xmpp for chat ?

Comment: I was loking for a simple chat, I dont know how work with xmpp

Comment: You can use firebase, gcm chat and openfire for xmpp.There are simple chat is GCM push notification chat.